# Using GPS locations to filter search on a mobile site.

Tags: javascript, mobile, gps

I am currently in the process of designing and moving onto the development of a mobile site which will utilise GPS location services and was looking for some advice.

First off this is what the site is about – my client operates a countryside trust and requires a mobile site, which walkers can access when out and about to find places of interest (pre-determined within a database). What my client want is for the user's mobile phone to determine their location via GPS and then they have the option to search for places within a chosen radius.

Essentially, has anyone seen something like this done? And does anyone know the technologies behind it and how it could be done?

Any help and collaboration would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well for fetching user's geolocation you can get it using HTML5 visit [here](http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation) for a demo. Then using this you can get the user's geolocation in coordinates. Now you said you have your database ready, then create a javascript function that helps you get the distance between places from their coordinates. For assistance with that visit [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). I guess this might complete your requirements.